# Shopify: Using variables from {% schema %} in Javascript

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have a custom section that uses the following schema:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Custom",
    "settings": [
    {
        "type": "textarea",
        "id": "custom_text_product",
        "label": "Insert name of the product here",
        "default": "Product"
      },
    {
        "type": "textarea",
        "id": "custom_text_msg",
        "label": "Custom text",
        "default": "Insert text here"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Basically what I want is to get the text from each textarea, manipulate via Javascript and then add it to the DOM.

Via `.liquid` I would simply do `{{ section.settings.id }}`, but I don't know how to access them in Javascript. Because it's a big text I can't add it to the DOM as a data-attribute either.

I have tried following [this](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/sections-referencing-json-schema-inside-javascript-424058) but no success.

Can someone help me or refer me to documents regarding this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so after much research and comments saying this was not possible, I found a way.

If you're on a `.liquid` file, you want to assign your {% schema %} variable to a local `.liquid` variable like this:

```
{%- assign product_text = section.settings.custom_text_product -%}
```

After that, you can access it in Javascript by doing so:

```
<script>
  var productText = `{{ product_text }}`;
</script>
```

I hope it helps everyone.

Comment: What if I want to set value of  `section.settings.custom_text_product` from js?
I want something like that

    <script>
      section.settings.custom_text_product = productText 
    </script>

Comment: @MuhammadTahir that is not possible. You can't attribute a Javascript value to a liquid variable. If you have this need, kindly carefully re-evaluate your code's architecture. There are no real-world use cases where this would be a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

So while this was exactly what I needed when I gave up on a timer I was setting up for checkout, I had to slightly change the code to get it working, but this is perfect:

```
{%- assign timer_amt = settings.timer -%}
var time_amt = `{{ settings.timer }}`;
```

I am not pulling from the section this is straight from the main Schema, so slightly different but a huge help.

Comment: To clarify, I would suggest updating your answer: if the JSON is within the section, it is `section.settings.timer`. If it's within the `settings_schema.json` file, then you access it via `settings.timer`